# how to find the maximum size of an array index?

Tags: c#

I declared an array

```
double[,] i=new double[2147483647,10] ; //2147483647=max size of int
```

but it throws out of memory exception

if I reduce the index 2147483647 to 21474836 it is working fine.

how I could know the maximum size of an array?

Comment: What the hell are you doing with over 210 million doubles?

Comment: Think about how big a `double` is and how many cells you are attempting to allocate.  A `double` is 8 bytes and you are trying to allocate `2147483647 * 10` cells (not including memory for the array metadata itself).  Does it sound reasonable to you to allocate 171,798,691,760 bytes (~160 GiB) of memory?

Comment: 2147483647 is 7FFFFFFF... it's the maximum you can have with 32bit

Comment: @Fischermaen..What the hell are you talking with over 210 million doubles?its over 2billion doubles..:)

Comment: @Fischermaen I am dynamically initializing the array so i could not predict the maximum size of array. but some time values large like this.

Comment: Yes, but you can estimate RAM needed to allocate that buffer and give up when it becomes too big!!! It's a nonsense to allocate such a big array!!

Answer (score 1):

maybe the reason is array indexing start with "0". so first element' index is "0" last "21474836".

Comment: original index is 2147483647 not 21474836.

Answer (score 0):

in that case it's (2^31).  I think it differs depending on whether your targetting 64-bit or 32-bit.